# $C^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap C_c(\mathbb{R})$ with $\|\cdot\|_{1,2}$ is not complete

Tags: functional-analysis

I need some help with proving the following:

Let $X = C^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap C_c(\mathbb{R})$, the space of $C^1$ functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with compact support, and for each $f \in X$, define $\|f\|_{1,2} = (\int_{[-\infty,\infty]}|f(x)|^2dx + \int_{[-\infty,\infty]}|f'(x)|^2dx)^{1/2}$. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\chi_n \in X$ be such that for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\chi_n(x) \in [0,1]$, $|\chi_n'(x)| \leq 1 \in [0,1]$, if $|x| \geq n+1$, then $\chi_n(x)=0$, and finally if $|x| \leq n-1$ then $\chi_n(x)=1$. Then:

$(1)$ $\|\cdot\|_{1,2}$ is a norm.

$(2)$ If a sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $X$ with norm $\|\cdot\|_{1,2}$ converges to $f$, then for each compact interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$, we have $(f_n|_I)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converging to $f|_I$ in $C(I)$ with norm $\|\cdot\|_2$ (defined for each $f \in X$ by $\|f\|_2 = (\int_{[-\infty,\infty]}|f(x)|^2dx)^{1/2}$).

$(3)$ If for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ we define $f_n=\chi_nf$ (which is in $X$) and if $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in $X$ with norm $\|\cdot\|_{1,2}$, then $f$ has compact support.

$(4)$ If for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we define $f_n(x)=\frac{\chi_n(x)}{(x^2+1)^{1/2}}$, then $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy in $X$ with norm $\|\cdot\|_{1,2}$.

$(5)$ $X$ with norm $\|\cdot\|_{1,2}$ is not complete.

What I have so far is:

$(1)$ Given $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ and $f,g \in X$, it's clear to me $\|f\|_{1,2}=0$ if and only if $f=0$ and $\|\alpha f\|_{1,2}=|\alpha|\|f\|_{1,2}$. On the other hand I'm not sure why $$\|f+g\|_{1,2} = (\int_{[-\infty,\infty]}|(f+g)(x)|^2dx + \int_{[-\infty,\infty]}|(f'+g')(x)|^2dx)^{1/2} \leq$$ $$(\int_{[-\infty,\infty]}|f(x)|^2dx + \int_{[-\infty,\infty]}|f'(x)|^2dx)^{1/2} + (\int_{[-\infty,\infty]}|g(x)|^2dx + \int_{[-\infty,\infty]}|g'(x)|^2dx)^{1/2} =$$ $$\|f\|_{1,2}+\|g\|_{1,2};$$ I strongly suspect (and have tried to use, of course) the Minkowski Inequality is going to show up here.

$(2)$ Suppose a sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $X$ converges to $f$. Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a compact interval, $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>N}$ we have $\|f-f_n\|_{1,2} < \epsilon$. Then $$\|f|_I-f_n|_I\|_2 = (\int_I|(f-f_n)(x)|^2dx)^{1/2} \leq$$ $$(\int_I|(f-f_n)(x)|^2dx + \int_I|(f'-f_n')(x)|^2dx)^{1/2} \leq$$ $$(\int_{[-\infty,\infty]}|(f-f_n)(x)|^2dx + \int_{[-\infty,\infty]}|(f'-f_n')(x)|^2dx)^{1/2} = \|f-f_n\|_{1,2} < \epsilon,$$ and $(f_n|_I)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $f|_I$ in $C(I)$ with norm $\|\cdot\|_2$

Is this correct?

$(3)$ For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$, define $f_n=\chi_nf$ and suppose $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in $X$ with norm $\|\cdot\|_{1,2}$ to, say, $F$. By $(2)$ we then know that for each compact interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$, we have $(f_n|_I)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converging to $F|_I$; let then $I=[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a compact interval, $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N>|a|,|b|$. Then if $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>N}$, we have $I \subset [-n+1,n+1]$, hence for each $x \in I$, $|f(x)-f_n(x)|=0$ (since), and therefore $$\|f|_I-f_n|_I\|_2 = (\int_I|f(x)-f_n(x)|^2dx)^{1/2} = 0 \leq \epsilon.$$ This means that for each compact interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$, $f_I=F_I$, so that in fact $f = F \in X$, and $f$ in fact has compact support.

Is this correct?

As for $(4)$ and $(5)$, I haven't made any progress yet, and I'd appreciate any hints. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: for (4), let be $m > n$; by symmetry:
$$
\|f_m(x) - f_n(x)\|^2 = 2\int_n^m\frac1{x^2+1}\,dx + 2\int_n^m\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^3}\,dx.
$$
You can bound easily this integrals.

For (5), convergence in this norm $\implies$ convergence in $L^2$ $\implies$ pointwise convergence a.e. for a subsequence. But the pointwise limit of $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is...